# How to perform time derivatives in Dask without sorting

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am working on a project that involves some larger-than-memory datasets, and have been evaluating different tools for working on a cluster instead of my local machine. One project that looked particularly interesting was dask, as it has a very similar API to pandas for its DataFrame class.

I would like to be taking aggregates of time-derivatives of timeseries-related data. This obviously necessitates ordering the time series data by timestamp so that you are taking meaningful differences between rows. However, dask DataFrames have no `sort_values` method.

When working with Spark DataFrame, and using `Window` functions, there is out-of-the-box support for ordering within partitions. That is, you can do things like:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
my_window = Window.partitionBy(df['id'], df['agg_time']).orderBy(df['timestamp'])
```

I can then use this window function to calculate differences etc.

I'm wondering if there is a way to achieve something similar in dask. I can, in principle, use Spark, but I'm in a bit of a time crunch, and my familiarity with its API is much less than with pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to set your timeseries column as your *index*.

```
df = df.set_index('timestamp')
```

This allows for much smarter time-series algorithms, including rolling operations, random access, and so on.  You may want to look at http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#rolling-operations.

Note that in general setting an index and performing a full sort can be expensive.  Ideally your data comes in a form that is already sorted by time.

#### Example

So in your case, if you just want to compute a derivative you might do something like the following:

```
df = df.set_index('timestamp')
df.x.diff(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. For each value of `'id'` and `'agg_time'`, all `'timestamps'` are unique, however, this isn't necessarily the case outside of those groups, and as far as I can tell, dask doesn't support MultiIndex DataFrames.If I perform a `groupby` on my dask DataFrame, can I set the index then, or will that significantly slowdown my calculation time?

Comment: You're correct that, as of now, dask.dataframe doesn't support multi-indexes.  If you're grouping on other keys first, and if the resulting groups are small enough to fit in memory, then I would just do groupby-apply and have your time-series logic be in a normal pandas->pandas function.  If your data is cut up like this then you may not need scalable time-series logic and the real job of a tool like Dask here is just to deliver up the groups appropriately.

Comment: For each grouping, the dataset is only 24 hours of data at 1 second intervals for approximately 20-30 sensors, so each group would itself be totally reasonable to fit into memory. In this case, what you're saying is that once Dask has served up the groups, and I have a `Dask.DataFrame.groupby` object, I can simply call `.apply(f)` where `f` is some function that consumes a `pandas.DataFrame` object, and returns a new one transformed in the way I would like?

Comment: Also, to be clear in this case there is no need to call `set_index`.  The groupby-apply will end up sorting anyway.